# Tell Joomla to be set to logged-in status via outside PHP script

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I have a site that I am migrating from Joomla 1.7 to 3.3 and the previous site had a PHP script that when someone logged into a different server that handles all membership accounts (and completely separate from Joomla) to go back to the Joomla site and change to logged-in status as a registered user.  How would I accomplish this in Joomla 3.3?

Here's a possible start (but incomplete):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($_GET['login']=='true'){
    $user->guest = 0;
}
```

Something like this might work, but at the very least I don't know what all settings Joomla needs to determine that the current user is logged in.

Comment: Do they have a userid on Joomla?  Are you doing this in a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
if($_GET['login']=='true'){
    $userid =   $_GET['userid']; //This is the user id which you get from remote website.
    $user = JFactory::getUser($userid);
    $session =& JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set("user",$user);
}
```

Using about code the user will be logged in on Joomla website.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me, but I appreciate the answer; thanks.